# GNU screen open tab in specific position and shift already opened tabs

Tags: gnu-screen

Is it possible in GNU screen to open tab in specified position and shift all tabs on the right side of this position? E.g. If I have opened tabs: `1 2 3 4` and I want to open new tab on position `2` I would like to end up with `1 [newly-opened-tab] 3 4 5` or in other words:

- new 1 will be same as old 1
- new 2 will be my new opened tab
- new 3 will be my old 2
- new 4 will be my old 3
- new 5 will be my old 4

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "tab"? Are you referring to ["panes"](https://tomlee.co/2011/10/gnu-screen-splitting/)?

Comment: @terdon by tab I mean "window" or what is the correct name (those which you will create by using ctrl+a+c)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but not with a single command. You could write a short script to handle it. You would basically need to:

- Open new tab
- While not at target number:

  - Determine current tab number (`$WINDOW`)
  - Determine number 1 closer to the target number (e.g. if current number is 5 and you want 2, then the number 1 closer is 4)
  - use the `number` command to swap the tab with the tab that's one closer (e.g. `screen -S <session_name> -p <current_number> -X number <one_closer_number>`)

You can also do the above manually using the Ctrl+a : keybinding and entering `number <one_closer_number>` (obviously replacing <one_closer_number> with the actual number that is one closer)

**Explanation**

Screen's `number` command will swap the current tab's number with the target number, so you have to trickle your way down to the target number if you want to shift all of the other ones over.